# How to create two different ion menus in one ionic app?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ion-menu

My app has two user types customer and staff and for each of them, I need different menus.
How can I add some condition in the app.component.html page like if this.usertype = "Staff" use the staff's menu else use the customer's menu.
I tried using a different Id but in this method, the first menu seems to disappear. Hope you can help me! Thanks in advance!

My current code in app.component.html

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<ion-app>
  <ion-menu menuId="main-menu" side="start" content-id="main-content">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar translucent>
        <ion-title style="font-family: 'Poppins';font-weight: 300;">Menu</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item routerLink="/homepagee">
          <ion-label style="font-family: 'Poppins'">Home</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item routerLink="/terms">
          <ion-label style="font-family: 'Poppins'">Terms & Conditions</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item routerLink="/privacy">
          <ion-label style="font-family: 'Poppins'">Privacy Policy</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item routerLink="/myaccount">
          <ion-label style="font-family: 'Poppins'">My Details</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item routerLink="/home">
          <ion-label style="font-family: 'Poppins'">Logout</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>


  <ion-menu menuId="main-menu2" side="start" content-id="main-content2">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar translucent>
        <ion-title style="font-family: 'Poppins';font-weight: 300;">Menu</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item routerLink="/homepagee">
          <ion-label style="font-family: 'Poppins'">Announcments</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item routerLink="/terms">
          <ion-label style="font-family: 'Poppins'">Terms & Conditions</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item routerLink="/privacy">
          <ion-label style="font-family: 'Poppins'">Privacy Policy</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item routerLink="/myaccount">
          <ion-label style="font-family: 'Poppins'">Chat</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item routerLink="/home">
          <ion-label style="font-family: 'Poppins'">Logout</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>

  <ion-router-outlet id="main-content"></ion-router-outlet>
  <ion-router-outlet id="main-content2"></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this scenario use `MenuController` Example:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'menu-example',
  templateUrl: 'menu-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu-example.css'],
})
export class MenuExample {

 constructor(private menu: MenuController) { 

   if(this.usertype = "Staff" ){
    this.menu.enable(true, 'Your_Staff_MenuID'); 
   }else{
    this.menu.enable(true, 'Your_Other__MenuID'); 
   }
 }   

}
```

You can find more information about how to control multiple menus with the `MenuController` in the [ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/2.3.0/api/components/menu/MenuController/).